# Issues regarding visibility of BottomSheetDialog

Tags: java, android

There seems to be an issue with my showUpdateDialog method.When the app runs, no dialog box appears.

Checked XML files for duplicate/conflicting names.

No Exception logged.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="6dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/etUpdateUserName"
            android:hint="Your Name"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/etUpdateUserAddress"
            android:hint="Your Address"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_update"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button_style"
            android:fontFamily="casual"
            android:text="Update Information"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>'


</LinearLayout>
```

my MainActivity, including the showUpdateDialog method:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@BindView(R.id.bottom_navigation)
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

CollectionReference userRef;

BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    ButterKnife.bind(HomeActivity.this);


    userRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("User");



    if(getIntent() !=null)
    {
        boolean isLogin = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(Common.IS_LOGIN, false);
        if(isLogin)
        {

            AccountKit.getCurrentAccount(new AccountKitCallback<Account>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final Account account) {
                    if(account !=null)
                    {
                        DocumentReference currentUser = 
userRef.document(account.getEmail().toString());
                        currentUser.get()
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new 
OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull 
Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                                        {
                                            DocumentSnapshot userSnapshot = 
task.getResult();
                                            if(!userSnapshot.exists())
                                            {

showUpdateDialog(account.getEmail().toString());
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }




                @Override
                public void onError(AccountKitError accountKitError) {
              Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, 
""+accountKitError.getErrorType().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }


    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
       Fragment fragment = null;
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_home)
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
            else if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_shopping)
                fragment = new ShoppingFragment();

            return loadFragment(fragment);
        }
    });


    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_home);

}

private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    if(fragment !=null)
    {

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, 
fragment)
        .commit();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private void showUpdateDialog(final String email)
{
    bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(HomeActivity.this);
    bottomSheetDialog.setTitle("One last step...");
    bottomSheetDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    bottomSheetDialog.setCancelable(false);
    View sheetView = 
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_update_user_information, null);

    Button btn_update = (Button)sheetView.findViewById(R.id.btn_update);
    final TextInputEditText edit_name = 
(TextInputEditText)sheetView.findViewById(R.id.etUpdateUserName);
    final TextInputEditText edit_address = 
(TextInputEditText)sheetView.findViewById(R.id.etUpdateUserAddress);

    btn_update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            User user = new User(edit_name.getText().toString(),
                    edit_address.getText().toString(),
                    email);
            userRef.document(email)
                    .set(user)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();

                            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Details 
updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }
                    }) .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e)
                {

                    bottomSheetDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, ""+e.getMessage(), 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });

    bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(sheetView);
    bottomSheetDialog.show();


}




}
```

I expect the bottomSheetDialogBox to show, inflating the layout_update_user_information.

Answer (score 0):

it is maybe because that you are not using proper context to show your dialog

in first line of your method

```
bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
```

where is the reference of your Context ?

it has to be your Activity or Fragment's context

try to change your methods parameters like this :

```
private void showUpdateDialog(Context context, final String email)
```

and pass the proper Context to your method, something like

```
showUpdateDialog(YourActivityClassName.this,"emailAddress");
```

or

```
showUpdateDialog(YourFragmentClassName.this,"emailAddress");
```

P.S :
make sure that you are calling your method from the UI Thread :

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
 public void run() {
      showUpdateDialog(HomeActivity.this,email);
 }
});
```

Comment: Firstly thank you for responding, I have updated the question to include my entire Activity where the method is called. When I tried to change the method parameters to include context an error sprung up on line:
    showUpdateDialog(account.getEmail().toString()); android.content.Context,
String)
in HomeActivity cannot be applied
to
(java.lang.String)

Comment: @croft you have two problems here, first of all getCurrentAccount runs on background thread so when you receive the result in onSuccess method, your codes runs on background thread, so you have to call your method on ui thread (check the edited answer), and about your String problem, try to use String.valueOf(account.getEmail());

Comment: Being a novice programmer I cannot get the method to run on ui thread, could you please show me how to implement it? When I try to implement your solution to the String problem the same error occurs as before: android.content.Context, String) in HomeActivity cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)

Comment: @croft comment your new method and method calling part

Comment: problem has been solved due to me spelling 'behavoir' as 'behaviour' when defining BottomSheetBehavior in the xml file...thank you for your help and quick responces.